# What calls Dispose() method in c# MSTest unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mockhttpmessagehandler

I currently reviewing a test class that uses MSTest and implements IDisposable. The test itself is testing a custom client and has an instance of

> MockHttpMessageHandler by RichardSzalay.MockHttp

which implements the IDisposable interface.

The following code has been added at the bottom of the class and gets called after each test. I am looking to confirm what calls the Dispose method that is declared in the test class

```
public void Dispose()
{
    _mockHttpHandler.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that will depend on which test framework you're using. Please add that information to the question. Also, have you tried debugging and just putting a breakpoint on the `Dispose` call, then looking at the stack trace?

Comment: Updated question to include MSTest as the test framework. The callstack only shows the current breakpoint location which is the Dispose method in the test class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSTest performs a type conversion check using the as operator and then calls the Dispose method in this case:

```
 private void RunTestCleanupMethod(object classInstance, TestResult result)
{
  MethodInfo methodInfo = this.Parent.TestCleanupMethod;
  try
  {
    try
    {
      if (methodInfo != null)
        methodInfo.InvokeAsSynchronousTask(classInstance, (object[]) null);
      Queue<MethodInfo> methodInfoQueue = new Queue<MethodInfo>((IEnumerable<MethodInfo>) this.Parent.BaseTestCleanupMethodsQueue);
      while (methodInfoQueue.Count > 0)
      {
        methodInfo = methodInfoQueue.Dequeue();
        if (methodInfo != null)
          methodInfo.InvokeAsSynchronousTask(classInstance, (object[]) null);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      (classInstance as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }
  }
```